# How do you reference a cell in quotations using the IMPORTXML formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I am wanting to reference a **cell** for the URL section as well as the xpath_query section of the IMPORTXML formula.

Because the XPath formula requires the inputs to be in quotations the cell references no longer work.

What would you suggest for the following formula?
=IMPORTXML(C2,B7)

C2 = https://www.example.com
B7 = //nav[@aria-label='test']

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what the issue is here.Which part of the `=IMPORTXML(C2,B7)` is not working? Does `B7` look like `"xpath_query"` or just `xpath_query`?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML(C2&B7; "//*")
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.